# Color the cell if the month has crossed 3rd month

Tags: excel, validation, datetime, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have data as below:

```
B2 = 23-Mar-2015
C2 = 09-Jun-2015
D2 = 17-Oct-2015
```

The formula should check for the **month** and `('B2' -  Mar')` once it crosses 3rd month (**May**) it should color the cell **Green**.

So, if 'B2'   -    today (only the month) then color the cell green.

Is it too much/ is it do-able?

Comment: It should be doable, but it is not clear precisely what you want. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wish this to apply to each of B2, C2 and D2, please select from B2 to D2 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(B2<>"",TODAY()>EOMONTH(B2,2))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green formatting, OK, OK.

This won’t trigger if the cell is blank but should when today is after the end of the second month following. So for March 23 not green on May 31, green on June 1.

To move by one month add/subtract `1` from the final `2` in the formula (may be negative).

Comment: Thank u so much. This is what exactly I wanted. :-)